# How to resolve 'Fields pending deletion' and force deletion of said field?

Tags: entities, installation

I'm stuck with an uninstallable module. Drupal insists that there are *Fields pending deletion* and that the module can not be uninstalled. I've run cron zillion times already as advised for such situations but without success. Cron runs fine, but drupal insists that still, *Fields pending deletion*.

Visiting `/admin/reports/fields` gives no clues - the fields provided by that module are not listed. I even tried using drupal console to uninstall module with `--force` switch, but also without success.

I also tried `drush field-info` in hope to get some clues, but that's apparently not yet implemented as drush `8.1.2` gives fatal error:

> Call to undefined function `field_info_fields()`.

How do I make drupal delete those fields that pending deletion? Do I have to do this manually in database?

I've seen few tables like `field_deleted_data_f5e7b87e32` or `field_deleted_revision_be01eddd10` but they are all empty. Is that even relevant?

Answer (score 6):

You could force field deletion using drush with the command:

```
drush php-eval  'field_purge_batch(500);'
```

or you could install devel module and go to */devel/php* and run

```
field_purge_batch(500);
```

Comment: This error is confusing and is being looked at for D11. In my case, I had so many fields awaiting deletion that this appeared to make no difference. [Try setting the purge batch size stupidly high and running several times - when it returns quickly, there are finally no fields left](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1331922#comment-13819436).